# A SharePoint 2007 Content Database has been migrated but SharePoint is still trying to access the old Database server

Tags: 2007, content-database

We had a legacy SharePoint 2007 which was using an old version of SQL Database. The Content Database was then migrated to a different SQL Server that was running on a newer version. This has caused the SharePoint 2007 instance to become inaccessible. The registry key that references which Database should be used has been updated however in the Logs for the SharePoint Instance we are still getting this issue;

```
Cannot connect to SQL Server. <ServerName> not found. Additional error information from SQL Server is included below.  [DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (Connect()).]SQL Server does not exist or access denied.
```

Is there anywhere else that we need to update the reference to the database other than the Registry?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to run `cliconfg.exe` to create a SQL alias. The alias name is the old SQL server name/instance and the target is your new SQL Server. This must be done on all SharePoint servers in the farm.

[Move all databases in SharePoint Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/sharepoint/administration/move-all-databases)